# how to embedding outlook to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, outlook

Is there a method of embedding SharePoint to accept and send emails

I have a SharePoint website but the clients that i have are not fond of using this to communicate with the development team, but rather they would like to use emails,  is there any method that i could use in order for me to allow the client team to use emails as a method of communication to the site and then i reply on the share point site and they get the email,

Answer (score 1):

I think [SharePoint Site Mailboxes](http://www.scinaptic.com/sharepoint-2013-site-mailboxes.html) could assist with this requirement.  The White Paper will assist with your understanding of Site Mailboxes, their benefit and limitations.  The easiest way to test them out is to sign up for an Office 365 Trial (as all the configuration has been performed for you).

Hope it helps.

Note: I'm directly connected with OnePlaceMail who is mentioned in the White Paper.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two different features:

- from e-mail to SharePoint: enable inbound e-mail in the list, and make sure you have the correct columns the e-mail will populate (for example the e-mail body will go in the Body column)
- from SharePoint to e-mail: you can either used an "Assigned To" field (the assignee will receive the notification) or subscribe your users to alerts